# Difference between anomaly detection and data quality check

Tags: anomaly-detection, quality-control

I am a beginner in ML and in my company i have been asked to come up with models that can check if there are data quality issue in any given table. It will be an unsupervised learning task and I only need to do univariate analysis ie at a time i will look for data quality issue in a single column of a given table.
Now here are my two questions

1. Is this problem same as anomaly detection so can I apply those models for data quality checks??
2. What is the difference between data quality and anomaly detection if there is any.

Answer (score 2):

This is such a difficult question to answer because 'data quality checks' is so broad, and even the definition of anomaly detection is not completely clear. Moreover, to give the best suggestions we would need to know a lot more about your use case. However will all that being said, I have prepared an answer which I hope raises interesting points which you could think about.

## Brief description of Anomaly Detection

It can be difficult to summarise anomaly detection (note that outlier is often used as a synonym for anomaly).
The following summary is a reasonable one:

> "Anomaly detection refers to the problem of finding patterns in data
> that do not conform to expected behavior. These non-conforming
> patterns are often referred to as anomalies, outliers, discordant
> observations, exceptions, aberrations, surprises, peculiarities or
> contaminants in different application domains. Of these, anomalies and
> outliers are two terms used most commonly in the context of anomaly
> detection; sometimes interchangeably."

(From [Anomaly Detection: A Survey](http://cucis.ece.northwestern.edu/projects/DMS/publications/AnomalyDetection.pdf), Chandola, Banerjee, Kumar)

The following pithy description of an outlier is from Hawkins 1980 Identification of Outliers, may also be helpful to keep in mind.
"An outlier is an observation which deviates so much from the other observations as to arouse suspicions that it was generated by a different mechanism"

(see Hawkins D., Identification of Outliers, Chapman and Hall, 1980.)

I'll give some 'textbook' applications of anomaly detection:

**Examples of Anomaly detection:**

- **Credit card fraud detection**: Looking for anomalies(outliers) in credit card transaction data, for example unusual patterns in spending, such as an abnormally large purchase or spending in a new location. An anomaly detection model might detect this transaction and some action may be taken - for example the bank temporarily blocks the payment or contacts the customers.
- **Fault detection, for instance in manufacturing:** We might monitor parameters like temperature, pressure, vibration and product dimensions in a production process. We can establish a baseline from historical data, and significant deviations from expected ranges or patterns can be flagged as anomalies or faults. e.g. sudden temperature spikes or irregular product dimensions. Anomaly detection methods can help us identify these anomalies (so we don't sell defective products), and allow us to take timely actions.

## Brief description of 'Data Quality' checks

Defining data quality is difficult (even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_quality) agrees!) - it depends a lot on what you are trying to do with the data as to how you would judge the quality. *The same data may be high quality for one use case but low for another.*
Broadly speaking, *we might consider data quality to refer to the overally reliability, accuracy, completeness, consistency and relevance of data, ensuring that it is fit for its intended purpose and can be trusted for decision-making and analysis.*

**Examples of things to consider:**

- How will the data be used? Age categories Child/Adult may be fit for some purposes, but for others we may need more granular ages.
- Missing data - are we missing data, how is the missing data recorded - are rows completely omitted or do they appear with some null value?
- Correctness. Is the data correct?  Note that the data can be correct, and still be low quality.

## Your specific problem and the overlap of the two

The relevance of anomaly detection techniques to your problem depends exactly on *what data quality issues you are trying to find*? Without more details it is impossible to precisely answer your question, however *I will raise a few points you might like to think about.*

You mention tables, it is possible to set up data quality tests for your tables (say in SQL) - which allow you to check for things such as null values or non-uniqueness of ids. ([see dbt tests](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/tests)).

You mention statistical models/machine learning, and so I wonder whether what you are really driving at here is detecting anomalies in your data and *assuming that these anomalies are symptoms of data quality issues*. However **I would caution you here to make sure you are familiar with the underlying processes in play here**. For example in the Fraud detection example above, if you had a column in your table with user transacation amount, then your model might detect an unusually large value - but this value may well be correct, and so there is no data correctness issue here - the data may also have been delivered to you in near real time, so in many regards this is high quality data. On the other hand, if you were analysing data collected by human researchers of children's heights, and you noticed an usually large height of 113 metres, then you would probably conclude this is a genuine data quality issue (whereby the researcher has recorded in metres rather than centremetres).

- Can you use simple rules to highlight certain anomalous values. For example values which are physically impossible (e.g. the weight in kilograms of a component cannot be negative).
- Do you have some baseline data and a general understanding of what your data should look like?
  -- You could use something as simple as a z-score to highlight values which are extreme in the sense that they are "far" from the mean value. In some contexts this might make sense but in others will be meaningless.
- How often is data recorded and when will you be running your checks (near real time? In batch at the end of the month?)
- You could compare two sets of data to see if there is a statistically significant difference in some statistic. However even if you find a difference, it does not necessarily mean there is a data quality issue.
- If you have time series data you could consider something like comparing the 'distance' of the current value with a rolling mean/median (see [Hampel filters](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/pracma/html/hampel.html)).

You should also think about **what it would mean if you run some rule or model and find there is a potential data quality issue with a piece of data**. Will a human review it? Will the data be omitted or will you replace it with some more 'suitable' value? (mean? median?) What is the cost of getting this wrong - for instance if you fail to detect incorrect data what would the consequence of this be on the business decisions? On the other hand, if you wrongly flag data as having some issue, what would the cost of that be (human operational costs?)

**To summarise, my advice for you would be to try to understand the underlying process which generates your data and bear this in mind when considering what 'unusual' means and is my unusual data actually 'incorrect'.**

Comment: Thank you this helps. I have data in a time series format. Can you give some more references like Hampel Filters.

Comment: Hi Srinath. If this answer is helpful please consider voting it up and/or marking it as the accepted answer. 
[Here](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2021/06/01/hampel-filter-robust-outliers.html) is a good, accessible, article on the Hampel filter and detecting outliers in time series. It is using the SAS language but should explain the idea.  There is a textbook Outlier Analysis by C. Aggarwal, with a chapter on time series, but I am not sure whether that would be at the right level. I cannot think of anything else I can recommend personally but I am sure you will find plenty on the web.

Answer (score 0):

In general there may be more aspects of data quality checking than anomaly detection, as elaborated in the excellent answer by 8e9yQBKVlIDwoIVegfkJ.

Also note that an anomaly is *not necessarily* a data quality issue. A data point/observation may be perfectly fine but still be an outlier or an "anomaly" because something special happened in the underlying process that is *correctly identified* by a good quality observation. It is important that anomalies are not necessarily wrong. They should be taken as indicating something of potential interest, but this may or may not be an issue with data quality. As written by 8e9yQBKVlIDwoIVegfkJ, this depends however on the exact aim of data analysis. Even a correct good quality observation that is actually an outlier can be a problem for certain statistical analyses, and may cause misleading results. As such it can still be seen as a data quality issue, but I think that this is a misnomer, and the problem really is potential lack of robustness of the planned analysis.

That said, anomaly detection is very often a major part of data quality checking, highlighting *potential* issues with certain observations (optimally then it can be checked what led to the anomaly and if it's really a data quality issue).

An alternative form of data quality checking that could be of interest is that you may have a good model of the existing understanding of the data generating process that is not driven by the data you want to check. If data deviate from this systematically, this might point to a data quality issue, and data might be systematically biased, even if none of the individual observations looks an anomaly compared to the others. (Alternatively it may point to flaws in the "existing understanding".)